# Tricky "Reopen Votes" audit

Tags: support, review-audits

The Reopen Votes queue gave me this:

[Omit inf from row sum in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393251/omit-inf-from-row-sum-in-r)

And I marked it to close, as it shows no research effort, and has several good answers already, and comments in the question says as much. It should be closed.

The audit failed me. It is not clear.

Comment: You should vote to close based on if the question is off-topic, duplicate, not constructive for SE, not a real question, or too localized. You should not vote to close just based on if the question looks basic, or if the OP shows their own research or not (use downvotes for that), or if the question has already been answered or not.

Comment: OK then this question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form

Comment: The accepted answer seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: I thought *"How do I sum the rows of a matrix, omitting the inf's?"* was pretty clear, unambiguous, not vague, not incomplete, not overly broad, and not rhetorical. It could also be reasonably answered in its current form, as seen by the answers posted.

Comment: The lack of effort shown is enough to deem it "incomplete".

Comment: @JoeFrambach The lack of effort could be worth a downvote, if you feel that it's of low quality.  That doesn't mean it's appropriate to close the question though.

Comment: Hey I'm not voting to close it, I voted to not re-open it. Which makes it not a fair audit prompt.

Comment: @JoeFrambach If the question shouldn't be closed, and it happened to have already been closed, then you *should* vote to reopen it, and the audit is right.  That's the whole idea of the queue.  You leave questions closed if they ought to be closed, and you vote to reopen them if they shouldn't be closed.  This shouldn't be closed (just downvoted at the most).

Answer (score 8):

The audit is right as far as I can tell. It looks like you're confusing downvotes with close votes.

That question arguably does not show much research effort, so it may have accumulated a little too many upvotes from the great answers it has produced. Go ahead and downvote it if you agree.

However, it does not deserve to be closed. It has no duplicate I could find, is not off-topic, is a real constructive question, and is not too localized.